# replaceInAll script working on cli but not as an .bashrc function

Tags: shell, sed, bash, bash-function

This .bashrc function is working on the command line,
its a nice bash one line'er.

but moving it into the bash profile and it stops working ?

`replaceInAll (){
  find . -name "$1" -print | xargs sed -i 's/$2/$3/g'
}`

what am i not getting wright with this ?

Comment: Are you sure `.bash_profile` is sourced for your shell? It's only sourced for login shells, not all interactive shells.

Comment: I am in linux box so its .bashrc,  and I have a have a functions working fine e.g  grepall (){
  find . -name "$1" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo %; grep "$2" %; echo "" ' _ "$@";
}

Comment: If your terminal emulator starts a non-login interactive shell, then you have to define the function in `.bashrc`. Functions are not exported, so your shells will not inherit the function from your initial login shell. (You could, however, try exporting the functions from `.bash_profile` using `export -f replaceInAll` and logging back in to see if the function is propagated to other shells. It's much simpler to just define the function in the correct file, though.)

Comment: mm,  well my function was available for me to use from the cmd.  but I swapped it out into the bash_profile but no change.  the function is not doing the replacing

Comment: Did you change the quotes when you moved it? The single quotes used in the `sed` argument prevent `$2` and `$3` from being expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

`replaceInAll (){ 
find . -name "$1" -print | xargs sed -i s/"$2"/"$3"/g 
}`